# What are some other terms like 'drop in' to describe a class that students can attend without the pressure of commitment?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

What are some other terms like 'drop in' to describe a class that students can attend without the pressure of commitment?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can also be referred to as "auditing a class", attending when you feel like it without the pressure of taking the class full time or completing the assessments attached to it.